# How to change username in top-right panel?

Tags: xubuntu, users

So I used 'Users and Groups' option under System to change my username and home directory, but even after I restarted, the top-right session panel has my old username. How can I change it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I've got the same problem, seeing logs like: http://pastebin.com/XHN37yK7 It just won't save it

Answer (score 2):

Using Ubuntu: Go to `System Settings` --> `User Accounts` and select your user account from the panel on the left.

On the right, you'll see all your account info. Click on your name beside the photo and edit!

You may need to logout and log back in for it to take effect.

Comment: I did this and it did not work after logging in and back out.